# JS: Image disapear after replacing src

Tags: javascript, python, real-time

I need to process data & display an image in realtime.

***This are the steps I am doing so far:***

**Process the data & Create the image [Python]**

1. I have created my python file to process the data, create the image, and store it in buffer.

**Display the image [Javascript]**

2. I recieve the image stored in the buffer and display it on my app.

**RealTime**

3. All the code is inside a setInterval(function()), so its updated every 1 second.
4. To replace the old image I use:
    `document.getElementById("div").replaceChild(newImage, oldImage);`
   *This works the first time but then doesnt work anymore. I know the data is coming well from python because I can see it coming from the buffer ( `console.log(dataImage)`).

**UPDATE:** I did what @charlietfl commented, and now the image appears for less than a second and then dissapear, and keep doing that all the time...
**My Code [UPDATED]:**

```
function sendToPythonRd3() {

                            const exePath = appPath + '/assets/py/readData.py'
                            const { execFile } = require('child_process');

                            var cmap = document.getElementById('selectCmap')
                            var cmapValue = cmap.value;
                            var python = require('child_process').spawn('python', [exePath, rd3File,
                                         cmapValue]);
                            python.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
                                dataImage = data.toString('utf8').slice(2, -1)
                                console.log(dataImage)
                                var x = document.createElement("IMG");
                                x.setAttribute("src", 'data:image/png;base64,' + dataImage + '');
                                x.style.display = 'block';
                                x.style.margin = 'auto';
                                x.style.height = '315px';
                                x.style.width = 'auto';
                                var imagenGpr = document.getElementById('imageGrp')
                                imagenGpr.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + dataImage + '';
}
```

[image]

**To sum up:**

The  `document.getElementById("grpDataIn").replaceChild(x, imagenGpr);` is not working like I need, it only replace the image the first time, even that all this code is inside a setInterval, so it should replace the image every 1 second.

**UPDATE 2:**

After displaying the image.src data on my console, I realized that the first time the src data is complete (with all the buffer image data inside), but the second time is incomplete:

First Time:

- console.log(imagenGpr.src):
- Data in the console: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh....and continue with all the buffer information...

Second Time:

- console.log(imagenGpr.src):
- Data in the console: data:image/png;base64

-And no more data, it seems that the buffer data does not enter on the src data, but is weird because the code is the same than the first time is running....!

I am getting old & crazy...

Comment: Just modify `src` of existing one

Comment: May be I didnt explain it in the best way. The src is already replaced everytime the data comes from the python file. x.setAttribute("src", 'data:image/png;base64,' + dataImage + '');

Comment: The problem  is that I dont know by the image doesnt get replaced...

Comment: But `x` is a new image element. I'm suggesting replace the `src` of the element that already exists. The one you are trying to replace

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the help, now I can see that the image is updated, but it dessapear very quickly. Any idea? thanks for the help

Comment: Not without seeing a demo that reproduces it

Comment: good idea, I will record a GIF a upload it! thanks

Comment: Could try that but really hard to debug from an image without being able to use debugging tools in a browser

Comment: Yes I understand, at least I am sure that the data from python is coming because I am displaying the buffer data on the right side. You can see that the image comes and dissapear.

Comment: Not a common problem and lots of possible reasons